# I want to know all about Mocking

Tags: solidity, dapps, hardhat, chainlink

I saw in Patrick Collins's video he used MockV3Aggregator.sol.

1. What is mocking?
2. Why we use mock?
3. How we use mock?
4. I read that mocking is used for testing, how it is used for testing?
5. Is there any use of mock except testing?

Answer (score 0):

@hacek
This has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665812/what-is-mocking

This is a bigger topic that can be researched online as part of "Test doubles".  I recommend starting with this article :https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html

However increasingly the community is using terms like mock for other types of test double like fakes and stubs. The lines can appear blurry.

PS: you will increase the likelihood of questions being answered if you follow this guide
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Asking good questions is a skill too!